# How to efficiently separate socket pollers using asyncio and zmq?

Tags: python, asynchronous, zeromq, python-asyncio

Let's say I want to implement an echo server and client using ZeroMQ (`pyzmq`) and `asyncio` (for its event loop, coroutines, etc.).

Now I want to add more reliability by adding a heartbeat. As I don't want to interact too much with my wonderful echo protocol, this heartbeat is done by both client and server on a dedicated pair of sockets.

From what I understand, the *way to go*™ is to create a new zmq socket in the server class, register it to the existing `Poller` and let the server class handle everything, from timeout calculation to sending beats. That works, of course.

But this is more complicated than it should be (that's a personal view). From the server point of view, 'heartbeats' are implementation details. What heartbeats are there for is to answer a simple question: "is the client still there?". More technically, I would like to setup and `Heartbeat` object that takes a timeout and an address. That `Heartbeat` object would do all the socket setup, beat-related socket polling, send actual beats and receive them.

From the server point of view, I would just use `client.is_alive()` when required. But that would require two socket pollers to work in parallel. I can achieve that with an executor, but that does not seem right. How would you do that?